# Reference folder on a remote server from a Python script

Tags: python, linux, shell, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I have a python script on an Ubuntu server. I want to execute it from within a folder (which contains sub-folders) on another Ubuntu server where I have read and execute permissions, but not write permissions. Then I want to store the output on the original server.

Here's what I have tried:

```
cat $HOME/.local/bin/mine.py | ssh user@2nd_server "cd /path/to/dir" python -g output_dir_on_1st_server
```

`-g` option is used for output of this python script

What's the simplest way for me to run a script from within a directory on a remote server? And what's the simplest way to store output from the script on the original server?

Comment: if they are network folders having them on separate servers shouldn't matter. Just use the folder path of the folder on the second folder. Also, post any code you have tried and you'll get a lot better response.

Comment: \\server1\folder would be the path to a folder on server 1 and \\server2\folder to a folder on server 2.

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                           
`cat $HOME/.local/bin/mine.py | ssh user@2nd_server "cd /path/to/dir" python -g output_dir_on_1st_server`                                                             
# -g option is used for output of this python script